# In Blazor client app after login top of home page says Hello + a very long hash code instead of user name

Tags: .net-core, blazor

After every login in a Blazor client app I see below picture and I have to refresh the page so It replaces the hash code with user name or email

[image]

loginDisplay.razor is where it supposed to show the name/email of the user:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!
        <a href="LogOut">Log out</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="Register">Register</a>
        <a href="Login">Log in</a>
</NotAuthorized>
```

I used the custom state provider found from this [article](https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/) by Chris Sainty.

- GetAuthentication searches in localStorage if there exists a saved token return a new state based on that otherwise creates a new.
- MarkAsAuthenticated lets the state provider know that a user logged in with provided email
- MarkAsLogedOut is the opposite of the above one.
- ParseClaimsFromJwt is reading the claims from the token

:

```
 public class ApiAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
 {
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;

    public ApiAuthenticationStateProvider(HttpClient httpClient, ILocalStorageService localStorage)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _localStorage = localStorage;
    }
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var savedToken = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(savedToken))
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", savedToken);

        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(savedToken), "jwt")));
    }

    public void MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string email)
    {
        var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email) }, "apiauth"));
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }

    public void MarkUserAsLoggedOut()
    {
        var anonymousUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(anonymousUser));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Claim> ParseClaimsFromJwt(string jwt)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        var payload = jwt.Split('.')[1];
        var jsonBytes = ParseBase64WithoutPadding(payload);
        var keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonBytes);

        keyValuePairs.TryGetValue(ClaimTypes.Role, out object roles);

        if (roles != null)
        {
            if (roles.ToString().Trim().StartsWith("["))
            {
                var parsedRoles = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(roles.ToString());

                foreach (var parsedRole in parsedRoles)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, parsedRole));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roles.ToString()));
            }

            keyValuePairs.Remove(ClaimTypes.Role);
        }

        claims.AddRange(keyValuePairs.Select(kvp => new Claim(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString())));

        return claims;
    }

    private byte[] ParseBase64WithoutPadding(string base64)
    {
        switch (base64.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2: base64 += "=="; break;
            case 3: base64 += "="; break;
        }
        return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add debug logs. That depends what your IDP responds

Comment: Hi @Sorush, I've updated both the code sample and the blog post. My apologies for the error. Something had got messed up when upgrading to a newer version of Blazor. Could I ask if you spot an issue on a post if you could leave a comment so I can fix it? It was mainly luck that I came to hear about this. 

Cheers, Chris

Comment: Thanks @Chris I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small problem in the code of that article, just pass Email instead of token. Note the name of the parameter in `void MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string email)`.

In AuthService.cs

```
((ApiA uthenticationStateProvider)_authenticationStateProvider)
   //.MarkUserAsAuthenticated(loginResult.Token);
     .MarkUserAsAuthenticated(loginModel.Email);
```